# How do I add a vector from a matrix into an empty matrix using for loop in python?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have an accelerometer sensor reading for x,y and z axis and I want to pass it to fft function. So I want to initialize a matrix(yf) with 3 rows and unknown column(all 3 rows have same number of values e.g n x m, n=3 but m is unknown). And I want to store the result of fft function into `yf` matrix but I dont know how to do that. I have background in c,c++ and matlab but when it comes to python, the syntax is so weird I am having a time implementing it.

To test my idea I have below my test code. I just want to know how to append a vector into an unknown dimension matrix.

```
a = np.linspace(1,30,30).reshape(3,10)
yf = []
d = [0,1,2]
for ii in d:
  yf.append(a[ii] for ii in a)
print(yf)
```

If I do this `yf` wil have the following result

```
[<generator object <genexpr> at 0x000001511CB4F190>, <generator object <genexpr> at 0x000001512B403F90>, <generator object <genexpr> at 0x000001512B43B040>]
```

I want `yf` to be similar to `a` but by appending the row vector from `a` into `yf`

```
[[ 1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.  7.  8.  9. 10.]
 [11. 12. 13. 14. 15. 16. 17. 18. 19. 20.]
 [21. 22. 23. 24. 25. 26. 27. 28. 29. 30.]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for ii in d:
    yf.append(a[ii])
```

or

```
for row in a: 
     yf.append(row)
```

will clean up the list append

or

```
yf = [ii for ii in a]
```

Working example:

```
In [65]: a = np.linspace(1,30,30).reshape(3,10)
    ...: yf = []
    ...: d = [0,1,2]
    ...: for ii in d:
    ...:   yf.append(a[ii])
    ...: 
In [66]: yf
Out[66]: 
[array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9., 10.]),
 array([11., 12., 13., 14., 15., 16., 17., 18., 19., 20.]),
 array([21., 22., 23., 24., 25., 26., 27., 28., 29., 30.])]
```

Turn the list of arrays into an array with:

```
In [67]: np.array(yf)
Out[67]: 
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9., 10.],
       [11., 12., 13., 14., 15., 16., 17., 18., 19., 20.],
       [21., 22., 23., 24., 25., 26., 27., 28., 29., 30.]])
```

or with a function in the concatenate/stack family:

```
In [69]: np.vstack(yf)
Out[69]: 
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9., 10.],
       [11., 12., 13., 14., 15., 16., 17., 18., 19., 20.],
       [21., 22., 23., 24., 25., 26., 27., 28., 29., 30.]])
```

We often get SO questions where people try to use `np.append` iteratively to do this, but this is harder to get right, and is slower.  Repeated list append followed by one array construction at the end is better.

Comment: Thank you sir. But when I do `print(yf)` the result is [array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9., 10.]), array([11., 12., 13., 14., 15., 16., 17., 18., 19., 20.]), array([21., 22., 23., 24., 25., 26., 27., 28., 29., 30.])]. Is this type perceive as matrix in python?

Comment: The list of arrays can be turned into a 2d array - see my edits

Answer (score 1):

Use [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) after adding an additional axis to the vector and simply add the 2 arrays with `+` or `np.add` like this -

```py
# (3,10) + (3, 1) -> (3,10)


a + np.array(d).reshape(-1,1)

#### OR ####

a + np.array(d)[:,None]

#### OR ####

a + np.array(d)[:, np.newaxis]
```

```
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9., 10.],
       [12., 13., 14., 15., 16., 17., 18., 19., 20., 21.],
       [23., 24., 25., 26., 27., 28., 29., 30., 31., 32.]])
```

Comment: but sir, how do I add a vector from a matrix into this new empty matrix. Sorry, I just edit my question.

Comment: I am a bit confused on what you are trying to do. why not just set `yf = a + np.array(d)[:,None]`, doesnt that solve your problem?